# How to include a superscript in a character string that will become part of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, formatting, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I'm writing a Markdown document, and want to include a table of parameters and their values. One of the parameter values is 10^9, but I can't figure out how to get the 9 as a superscript within the character string. I tried using "expression()", but I "cannot coerce class ‘"expression"’ to a data.frame".

Here's a version that works to give you an idea of what I'm going for:

```
Parameters <- c("r, Intrinsic growth rate of parasite", "k, Rate of destruction of parasite by host immune system", "ρ, Maximum growth rate of the immune system", ", Parasite density at which growth rate of host immune system is half its maximum","D, Lethal within-host parasite density")
Values <- c("0.1-2.0", "0.001", "1", "1000", "10^9")
parms_table <- data.frame(Parameters, Values)
library(knitr)
kable(parms_table, caption = "Table 1")
```

Which ends up looking like this (in the preview):
[image]

I want that "10^9" shown as a 10 with an actual superscript of 9.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance! :)

Comment: Just use Markdown syntax there as "10<sup>9</sup>"

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! :)